# how to get start and end time of a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

I want to send the mail after the build where I need the Start and End time of the Jenkins build.

Is there a variable or anything which can help to get the start and end time of the Build.

I checked there is a Timestamp Plugin which is we are using for the Build name where we are showing the timestamp.

I am not able fetch the start and end time of the from timestamp plugin.

Comment: You can get the `timestamp` (start) and `duration` (length) from the regular JSON API, then it's a simple calculation to get the end time.

Comment: How do you send email? From Jenkins or using some external service?

Comment: from Jenkins with the help of plugin